# Xamarin Tab page not showing the icon for cross platform

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am creating a tabbed page in Xamarin by using :

```
class UITabbedPages : TabbedPage
{
    public UITabbedPages()
    {
        var landingPage = new FirstPage();
        landingPage.Icon = new FileImageSource() { File = FontAwesome.FARocket };
        landingPage.Title = "FirstPage";

        var location = new 2ndPage();
        location.Icon = FontAwesome.FABars;
        location.Title = "Location"

        this.Children.Add(landingPage);
        this.Children.Add(location);
    }
}
```

I used the two different things to show the icons but these both are not working.

Comment: what is the type of FontAwesome.FABars?

Comment: This is a icon of Fontawesome.

Comment: Did you tried to use a icon from resources? It worked?

Comment: No, I have not tried that. But i tried.  tilesPage.Icon = new FileImageSource() { File = FontAwesome.FABars }.

Comment: Please try with a image from resources and tell me if it worked.

Comment: I have tried the to access the image from Resources , By Using "tilesPage.Icon= FileImageSource.FromFile("bars.png");" But it can not be compiled .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115966/discussion-between-aniket-sharma-and-jzeferino).